# Using phpmyadmin to import Unicode hex codepoint data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I am trying build a database containing chinese unicode data from the unihan.zip files provided by unicode.

However the file only provides the characters in the assigned hex code point. (e.g. "U+547D").

My thinking was to manually convert (using excel?) each of these code points such as "U+547D"  to "命" before saving it as a CSV UTF-8 to import using phpmyadmin to mysql which i know works.

Just wondering if phpmyadmin or mysql would be able to accept this hex codepoint format as a more direct way of importing this data?

I have searched quite a bit for this answer but have not found any.  I have also tried importing it in a number of ways such as using char function but the table was updated with just "0x547D" instead of "命".

Any insight and help to this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any advice? *crossed fingers*......sigh

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use PHP to convert "0x547D" to decimal and then create a utf-8 formatted char like "命", before saving the data into the DB. If so, have a look at the portable-utf8.php library, which includes a utf8_chr() function.

By the way, thank you for letting me know about unihan.zip... I was looking for a free and good source for Han characters.

Comment: Liopic, thanks for your ideas. Hv looked at portable-uft8 and think it will br useful. I am still relatively new at php and mysql so lots more to learn. Any idea if it is just a matter of uploading the unihan file to mysql as it is as codepoints and then handling each query with the suggested utf8_char function?

Comment: Unless you need to work with codepoints for some reason (I can't spot one) it makes more sense to store the utf8 char itself. That is, "命" instead of 547D. The only thing is that you need to explicitly set the MySQL connection to use UTF-8 in your PHP code. It's just executing the following query before starting: "SET NAMES 'utf8'". Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Liopic, thanks for your response. pls bear with me if you could, with a php newbie. Under import tab in phpmyadmin, is there a way to indicate importing unihan file to convert all the codepoints to utf8 char automatically? or do you mean i need to import the unihan file with its codepoints as is 1st to database and then use php code to convert every single codepoint in the imported unihan database to its utf8 char equivalent? appreciate your patience and guidance.

Comment: I meant you have to code some program in PHP (or actually any other language) to convert the codepoints. As you are new to php, you may want to directly import the file to the database and work on it (assuming you know SQL). After importing you can create a new field, and later populate it using a query like: UPDATE tableName set hanChar = char(conv(codepoint, 16, 10) USING ucs2);

Comment: Thanks liopic understand what you are saying. will try this approach and see how goes. Thx heaps for pointing the way :)